# Opposite of php integer

Tags: php, drupal

I have a script:

```
if ($flag && $flag->is_flagged(arg(1))) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

How can it return true if it is not flagged? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the not condition !

```
if ($flag && !$flag->is_flagged(arg(1))) {
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I thik the OP would want `if ($flag && !$flag->is_flagged(arg(1))) {` OR just adding an `else` statement `else return FALSE`

Comment: @relentless Probably, I assumed that those two conditions are to check if its flagged.

Comment: THANK YOU Relentless and Aziz. I needed relentless's version but thank you both for help. I am so grateful.

Comment: @Michael You are welcome. I updated the code to reflect relentless validation.